# Remove permalink for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

I have multiple custom post types and custom taxonomies, "staff", "games", which have the permalinks:

```
domain.com/staff/%staff-name%
domain.com/games/%game-name%
```

However, I'm only using these custom posts to store data and am displaying it collectively on different pages.  How do I get the paths, such as, /staff/%staff-name% to redirect to the 404 page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you set the "rewrite" argument to "false" when registering the custom post type, no rewrite rules will be generated.

Comment: Additionally, if you don't want them to be queryable on public facing pages, you may also wish to set `query_var` to false, but note that doing so disables preview for that type - ie. preview post.

Comment: @t31os: Ha, that's interesting! But of course, if you only use the custom posts in other situations, the preview doesn't matter that much. Unless you create a special preview template that combines all these different situations. (But I think you need to play with `template_include` for that, there is no special template file name for previews?)

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as a preview template, but it's interesting idea... templates for post previews.

Answer (score 0):

Setting these posts as "private" should do what you want - (unless I misunderstood your question)